# c++ How to add value at the beginning of the array and index it?

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
void DArray<T>::add(T value){

    if (currentNum==size){

        size=size*2;

        delete [] dArray;
    }
    dArray[0]=value;
    currentNum++;
}
```

I just started to learn c++ and learning all these pointer and dynamic array stuff. Really suffering at how to add the value at the beginning of the array and make the value index to the next one such as position+1. Can anyone point out why my value did pass to only dArray [0] when I use `cin` but did not index to next position.

```
int val;
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        cout << "Please enter integer value number "<<i<< ": ";
        cin >> val;
        dInt.add(val);
        dInt.printAll();
    }
```

Comment: Creating custom containers is pretty advanced stuff. Normally you'd learn C++ basics such as using `std::vector` first, and tackle undersanding how to create something similar yourself later...

Comment: Because you only set `dArray[0]=value`. Are you looking for `dArray[currentNum]=value`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the new value at the end of the array?

Comment: @hyde I am trying not to use vector first to learn deeper

Comment: @ThomasSablik I doubt it work....

Comment: @rustyx I am using two way of adding, where I can at it at the end and the beginning

Comment: Why do you doubt it? Did you try it?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yup I do, it will just add it to the end of the array

Comment: It seems your question is unclear for me. Are you looking for a [deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) where you can push_front and push_back?

Comment: Also, when you reach the allocated size, you delete the old array and then try to add an item to an non existant array. And no data is ever copied from the old array to the new one.

Comment: Your method seems to be missing a few steps. Start with creating the new, bigger array. Then add the first element to the new array. Then copy the content of the old array to the new one (after the new first element). Then delete the old array.

Comment: If you find yourself making your own container, you usually have enough experience at that point to be able to figure things out for yourself

Comment: @Phil1970 yup I applied for my copy constructor and works now, thanks for head up

Comment: Ok, just keep in mind that in "real" applications, there are very few reasons to ever use new/delete (there are some cases, like Qt framework needing you to use `new` sometimes, because Qt will then use `delete`), and if your "real" code does that, most of the time you are doing something in a wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Creating your own container class is actually quite a hairy task. Typically most containers are implemented using *global new/delete* to allocate raw bytes, and then elements are added by calling *placement new*.

This code is untested, but should be along the right lines (ish). The code could be improved using std::move, but I'll leave that for now...

```cpp
template <class T>
void DArray<T>::push_back(const T& value) {

    if (currentNum == size) {

        // just in case size is zero, or something like that
        size = std::max(size + 2, size * 2);

        // allocate memory (but don't construct objects, yet)
        T* temp =  ::operator new (sizeof(T) * size);

        // copy construct each element
        for(auto i = 0; i < currentNum; ++i)
        {
          // we have to use placement-new here :/
          new (temp + i) T(dArray[i]);

          // destroy old item
          dArray[i].~T();
        }

        // free the old memory 
        ::operator delete (dArray);

        // update to the new array
        dArray = temp;
    }

    // copy construct the new element
    new (dArray + currentNum) T(value);

    // increment the count
    currentNum++;
}
```

Adding to the start of the array involves moving each element up in the array. As a result, it's a little bit more involved.

```cpp
template <class T>
void DArray<T>::push_front(const T& value) {

    if (currentNum == size) {

        // just in case size is zero, or something like that
        size = std::max(size + 2, size * 2);

        // allocate memory (but don't construct objects, yet)
        T* temp =  ::operator new (sizeof(T) * size);

        // copy construct each element
        // this time iterate in reverse
        for(auto i = 0; i < currentNum; ++i)
        {
          // copy old array into new array (starting at index 1)
          new (temp + i + 1) T(dArray[i]);

          // destroy old item
          dArray[i].~T();
        }

        // free the old memory 
        ::operator delete (dArray);

        // update to the new array
        dArray = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        // copy old elements in array (traverse in reverse order)
        for(auto i = currentNum; i > 0; --i)
        {
           // construct new item (copying previous element)
           new (dArray + i) T(dArray[i - 1]);

           // call dtor on old element
           dArray[i - 1].~T();
        }
    }

    // construct first element in array
    new (dArray) T(value);

    // increment the count
    currentNum++;
}
```

... and for completeness, the destructor.

```cpp
template <class T>
DArray<T>::~DArray()
{
   for(auto i = 0; i < currentNum; ++i)
   {
     // call destructor on each element
     dArray[i].~T();
   }

   // free the memory
   ::operator delete (dArray);
}
```

This is a reason most people just end up saying "use std::vector"...